# Is there a name for a 2-dimensional dumbbell like shape?

Tags: terminology, geometry

Is there a mathematical name for a 2-dimensional shape in the general form of a dumbbell?  That is two circular nodes connected by a center beam such as shown in this image from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/300885/5886).  It could also be thought of as a circle that has been pinched together.  I believe topology does not help us here since there are no holes, and thus such as shape is the same as a circle, but perhaps geometry gives us a name for it?

[image: dumbbell]

Comment: Looks a bit like a nephroid but it's not quite right. Feels like there should be a name for it though.

Comment: I doubt there is a general name, but there are curves with this kind of shape, for example the [epitrochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitrochoid) with $x=\cos t + \frac14 \cos 3t$ and $y=\sin t + \frac14 \sin 3t$

Comment: See [hippopede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopede).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape reminds of a Cassini oval (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassiniOvals.html) but without a more precise equation, one cannot be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

$$x^4-4(x^2-y^2+0.5)=0$$

Comment: They're asking for the name of the shape, not an equation.